# Regex for multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will match the following:

http://myurl.com/en/something

I need it to match the http://myrurl.com part exactly and then and 2 character code for the "en" and then anything after that. Whats the bets regex for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about;

```
var m = s.match(/(http:\/\/myurl.com\/)([a-z]{2})(\/.*)/i);

if (m) {
   print (m[1]);
   print (m[2]);
   print (m[3]);
}

>>http://myurl.com/
>>en
>>/something
```

Comment: If possible I try to use another delimiter (e.g. #) than forward slash so that I don't have to change those in the regex each time I copy between code and regex programs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(https?://[\w\d-]+\.[\w]+)/([\w\d-]+)/(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex can match many parts of a URL

```
/^((http[s]?):\/\/)?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*?)?(#[\w\-]+)?$/im
```

example = https://www.google.com/dir/1/2/search.html?arg=0-a&arg1=1-b&arg3-c#hash

Resulting in matches:

1: (https://) - protocol

2: (https) - protocol

3: (www.google.com) - host

4: (/dir/1/2/) - path

5: ([]) - segments of path array

6: (search.html) - file

7: (?arg=0-a&arg1=1-b&arg3-c) - query

8: (#hash) - hash